# CSS container div not getting height

Tags: css, css-float, liquid-layout

I want my container div to get the height of max of its children's height. without knowing what height the child `div`s are going to have. I was trying out on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtdfY/2/). The container `div` is on red. which is not showing up. Why?

Answer (score 288, accepted):

Add the following property:

```
.c{
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will force the container to respect the height of all elements within it, regardless of floating elements.
http://jsfiddle.net/gtdfY/3/

### UPDATE

Recently, I was working on a project that required this trick, but needed to allow overflow to show, so instead, you can use a pseudo-element to clear your floats, effectively achieving the same effect while allowing overflow on all elements.

```
.c:after{
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gtdfY/368/

Comment: Basically, adding this property forces the outer box to ignore the rule that floating containers have, where they are not calculated in height for containers, and apply them for the full background drawing.

Comment: Wow, I was like, "What? that won't work." But I'll be darned. I totally thought it wasn't going to behave properly. Thanks

Comment: Isn't this quite hacky really? To me, it defeats the purpose of overflow. I don't understand *why* this is the correct and most upvoted answer.

Comment: @AndrewWeir I'll admit, until now, I hadn't been entirely sure why this method of expanding containers to correctly consider floats in their size worked. [According](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) [to](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-clearing-floats-with-overflow) [several](http://annevankesteren.nl/2005/03/clearing-floats) [sources](http://www.mezzoblue.com/archives/2005/03/03/clearance/), it seems that this causes an element to change its rendering mode, from allowing visible overflow to *not* doing so, and in doing so, this forces elements to disallow that overflow.

Comment: The first way, using overflow, works for me. The second way ALSO works and seems less risky in case I have overflow in the future. I only wish I could upvote twice.

Comment: it worked for me , i had this issue for a long time , i've tried with overflow .. but not what i wanted , your answer does the trick , thanks .

Comment: using the updated version and it works like a charm. Still do not understand why it is working though.

Comment: i've reduced the code on jsfiddle producing the same effects http://jsfiddle.net/kpxq2eyn/9/ think it's easier to understand. And there is another weird solution which is adding  `float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding:0;' to the parent container

Answer (score 28):

You are floating the children which means they "float" in front of the container.
In order to take the correct height, you must "clear" the float

The div style="clear: both" clears the floating an gives the correct height to the container. see http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/clear.htm for more info on floats.

eg.

```
<div class="c">
    <div class="l">

    </div>
    <div class="m">
        World
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both" />
</div>
```

Comment: This clear: both; thing seems to be a proper solution for container's height, because the issue is the floating children. So this approach seems better rather than the overflow: hidden; one above.

Comment: Thanks @Yoeri for sharing this simple solution. Thumbs up!I's looking for the same solution for my new design as it's been nearly 6 years since I last designed a web layout after I solely focused on PHP development perspective rather design side.

Answer (score 20):

It is not that easier?

```
.c {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is :D. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try inserting this clearing div before the last `</div>`

`<div style="clear: both; line-height: 0;">&nbsp;</div>`

Answer (score 3):

The best and the most bulletproof solution is to add `::before` and `::after` pseudoelements to the container. So if you have for example a list like:

```
<ul class="clearfix">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

And every elements in the list has `float:left` property, then you should add to your css:

```
.clearfix::after, .clearfix::before {
     content: '';
     clear: both;
     display: table;
}
```

Or you could try `display:inline-block;` property, then you don't need to add any clearfix.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue, and I have come up with four total viable solutions:

1. Make the container `display: flex;` (this is my favorite solution)
2. Add `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: hidden;` to the container
3. Add the following CSS for the container:

```
.c:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
```

4. Make the following the last item inside the container:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue and after some research I belive using `display: flow-root` on the containing element is the correct approach.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) on the `clear` property:

> If an element contains only floated elements, its height collapses to nothing. If you want it to always be able to resize, so that it contains floating elements inside it, set the value of the element's display property to flow-root.

So while `clear: both` works (as other answers suggest), it is actually designed to correctly position other elements **inside** the same container respecting the height of the floating elements. `display: flow-root` should be used to make **the containing** element respect the heights of all it's children so other elements (e.g. **siblings** to the containing element) can be positioned properly.