# Percentage sizing CSS

Tags: html, css, web

My header doesn't appear anywhere. I would like to know how to fix it.

```css
body {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  font-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
nav {
  height: 8%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: 1000;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/50/50");
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1>...</h1> 
</nav>

<header>
</header>
```

Comment: How can we help you without you giving us the HTML. Give full code.

Comment: Its all ok on my side, are you passing the image path `url` correctly?

Comment: `header` has no height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would do the trick:

```
html, body {height:100%;}
```

if you use percentage for height the parent needs to have a fixed height (so actually it's 8% of something) or at least ALL parents till `html` tag need to have a percentage height.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be give that header element some (html-)content (like text) or specify a height explicitly as of my experience container elements are not "shown" when their boundaries are not declared in any way.

Otherwise you may have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876369/div-has-no-height-when-there-is-img-inside-it) as this seems to be the same problem basically to me.

If you are using e.g. Firefox, you can use rightclick->inspect element to see if the element is simply not rendered (i.e. because of no height) or otherwise trace the applied css, manipulate css in place (non permanent) or even debug javascript.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The header tag has no contents, and therefore 0 height.  Try adding some text inside the header tags or add a height with css.